# Facebook PHP app: infinite loop when logging in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, infinite-loop, facebook-login

I am developing a simple Facebook Canvas app using the latest PHP SDK (v4). The first page (index.php) displays the Facebook permissions pop-up (it only asks for the public profile and the email address) and then lets the user to enter certain data through a form. Some other user's data are retrieved from the API and stored in PHP session variables. After the form is submitted, the user is taken to a second page (thanks.php) where the session variables are saved in a database. The app is located in /facebook/email.

Here is my code. Part of it has been taken from https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once( '../funciones.php' );
    require_once '../facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';

    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

    $yaparticipo = false;

    $app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $app_namespace = 'xxxx';
    $app_scope = 'email';

    // Facebook APP keys
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);

    // Helper for fb canvas authentication
    $helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

    // see if  $_SESSION exists
    if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['fb_token']))
    {
        // create new fb session from saved fb_token
        $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);

        // validate the fb_token to make sure it's still valid
        try 
        {
                $session->validate();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // catch any exceptions
            $session = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // no $_SESSION exists
        try
        {
            // create fb session
            $session = $helper->getSession();
        }
        catch(FacebookRequestException $ex)
        {
            // When Facebook returns an error
            //print_r($ex);
            $session = null;
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex)
        {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            //print_r($ex);
            $session = null;
        }
    }



    // check if 1 of the 2 methods above set $session
    if (isset($session))
    {
        // Lets save fb_token for later authentication through saved $_SESSION
        $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');

        // retrieve some data and store it in session variables
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Facebook app</title>

        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- submit email form -->
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else {
        session_destroy();
        $oauthJS = "window.top.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/$app_namespace/&scope=$app_scope';";
        echo "<script>" . $oauthJS . "</script>";
    }
?>
```

For some reason, most of the times the app works well, but sometimes it gets stuck in an infinite loop when it should display the pop-up. The canvas remains blank and the browser seems to be in an eternal "loading" state.

According to Firebug, the redirection isn't working properly. Also, for some reason, the browser can't load an image from a Facebook domain. Look at the following screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl0G9.jpg

I've found many fixes all around the web (searching for *facebook login php infinite loop*), but nothing works. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: done any debugging, like seeing if any of those `catch` blocks file? If $session gets nulled, then you'd just keep issuing that window.location redirect.

Comment: It seems that `$_SESSION['fb_token']` is not being set, so the the first "else" branch is executed and tries to set `$session`. But this doesn't work either, so `$session` remains null and it finally goes to the last "else" branch, where the script redirects to the same page again. So I think this line
`$session = $helper->getSession();`
is not working properly, but I don't know why (`$helper` looks OK).
As I said before, this only happens from time to time.

Comment: Have you already inspected all the variables in the different states to see if there are any hints that could point to a potential error?